# Can't get ItemStack value from own class

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm trying to create my own 1.16 Minecraft plugin.
I have the class:

```
public class Ore {
    private final String name;
    private final ItemStack tool;
    private final ItemStack drop;
    private final Double chance;
    private final Integer cooldown;

    public Ore(String name, ItemStack tool, ItemStack drop, Double chance, Integer cooldown) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tool = tool;
        this.drop = drop;
        this.chance = chance;
        this.cooldown = cooldown;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ItemStack getTool() {
        return this.tool;
    }

    public ItemStack getDrop() {
        return this.drop;
    }

    public Double getChance() {
        return this.chance;
    }

    public Integer getCooldown() {
        return this.cooldown;
    }
}
```

And other class, in which I use first one:

```
public class ResourceManager {
    public static Ore stoneOre = new Ore(ChatColor.GRAY + "Cobblestone", OreItems.t1PickAxe, new ItemStack(Material.REDSTONE_ORE, 1), 80.0, 30);
}
```

Result:

```
Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ResourceManager.stoneOre.getName() + " " + ResourceManager.stoneOre.getChance() + " " + ResourceManager.stoneOre.getCooldown() + " " + ResourceManager.stoneOre.getDrop() + " " + ResourceManager.stoneOre.getTool());

[Console]: Cobblestone 80.0 30 null null
```

There shouldn't any nulls values (ItemStacks), but they are.
What is the reason why I am getting null from getTool() and getDrop() methods? ItemStack cannot be used like this or what is the reason?
With other methods everything is OK.

Comment: You are initialazing the object with a OreItems attribute for the ItemStack tool.

Comment: @Gabitohh
That is external class that stores static ItemStacks that i made in constructor like this

public static ItemStack stoneOre = new ItemConstructor(Material.COBBLESTONE)
            .amount(1)
            .displayName(ResourceManager.stoneOre.getName())
            .lore(ChatColor.GRAY + "[✰✰✰✰✰] Material")
            .build();

Comment: You don't have enough of your code for us to reasonably tell what is going on. What are the `OreItems` and `ItemStack` classes? When are you creating and setting the info for these classes compared to your method call? Is `Material.REDSTONE_ORE` a Enum or a class variable? Ect.

Comment: My initial assumption is that because you are initializing the `stoneOre` variable as a static variable outside your constructor, it is trying to do initialization for that before the system knows what the information you're passing it is so it defaults to a `null` value. But without more information it's hard to tell.

Comment: The problem has been solved.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone who may stumble across this post, it's okay to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).